# Occurence of number $1$ in the sequence $a_n=2^n$

Tags: limits, elementary-number-theory

So I was just calculating the terms of the sequence $a_n=2^n$ for $n=1,2,...50$ and discovered that among the first fifty terms there is $31$ term that has number $1$ in itself (in base $10$, of course).

It seems that as we go further in the sequence that the terms that contain $1$ in itself become more and more common.

Let us denote by $m(n)$ the number of numbers in the set $\{2^1,...,2^n\}$ that contain number $1$ when written in base $10$ (so I calculated that $m(50)=31$).

> Can someone evaluate the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {m(n)}{n}$?

Comment: Well, as n increases the number of digits increase so the likelihood of any digit increases.  It'd be hard for me to believe the limit isn't one as when we have a large number of digits the odds that none of them being 1 would be can be arbitrarily small with enough digits.

Comment: @fleablood I also believe that the limit is one but do not know how to prove it.

Comment: Well assume digits are distributed normally.  Then the number of digits in $2^n$ is $n \log_{10} 2$.  probability that the number has a 1 in it is $1 - .9^{n\log_{10}2}$.  So the total m(n) is roughly $\int_0^n (1-.9^{x\log_{10}2})dx= n - \log_{10} 2 \ln .9 * .9^{n\log_{10}2} - 1$ so m(n)/n is aproximately equal to $1 - \frac{ \log_{10} 2 \ln .9 * .9^{n\log_{10}2} - 1}n$ and the limit of that is clearly 1.

Comment: @fleablood Under the assumption that the digits are distributed normally, yes, but is there any strong reason to assume that?

Comment: ... or you could simply claim that in probability theory the probability of any event with a non-zero probability of occurring in an infinite number of iterations is 1.  As the number of digits in $2^n$ approaches infinity the number of terms with 1 become all of them.  So m(n)/n approaches 1.

Comment: Why not?  I think it's up to people to prove it is not normal if we are to believe there is something about 1 that *prevents* it from occurring normally.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is $1$.  In general, almost all numbers contain a $1$, or any digit sequence you care to name.  For the powers of $2$, you can make it explicit.  After $2^0=1$ the ones digits of the powers of $2$ cycle $2,4,8,6$.  The last two digits go through a cycle of length $20$, being all the multiples of $4 \pmod {100}$ that do not end in zero.  Of those, $2$ have a $1$ in the tens digit: $12$ and $16$.  The last three digits go through a cycle of length $100$, being all the multiples of $8 \pmod {1000}$ that do not end in zero.  Of those that do not have a $1$ in the tens digit, $\frac 1{10}$ have a $1$ in the hundreds digit.  The pattern continues:  the fraction that do not have a $1$ in any of the last $n$ digits is $(\frac 9{10})^{n-1}$.  This goes to zero as $n \to \infty$

Comment: You have not proved that the limit is 1, just made it plausible.

Comment: @almagest:  no, this is a(n outline of a) proof.  In $\epsilon-N$ language, if you ask for an $N$ so that the proportion of numbers greater than $N$ that do not have a $1$ is less than $\epsilon$, I need them to have at least $n$ digits such that $0.9^{n-1} \lt \epsilon$, and I can choose $N$ large enough to make it so.

Comment: I don't see where you have proved that you can choose $N$ to guarantee that the proportion of numbers greater than $N$ without a 1 is less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: I can see that increases in the number of 1s get "locked in" because the last $k$ digits cycle. But where have you proved that you keep on getting increases?